# A set has been encountered that cannot contain calculated members error in MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx

Am executing the below query in SSAS server,

```
*SELECT*   ([Measures].[Internet Average Sales Amount]) ON COLUMNS 
    FROM 
    (
      select [Measures].[Internet Average Sales Amount] on 0,
      [Product].[Category].[Category].members on 1
      *From [Adventure Works]*
    )
```

I got A set has been encountered that cannot contain calculated members error

Answer (score 1):

Try omitting the calculated measure in the subselect in the FROM clause:

```
SELECT   ([Measures].[Internet Average Sales Amount]) ON COLUMNS 
    FROM 
    (
      select [Product].[Category].[Category].members on 0
      From [Adventure Works]
    )
```

Actually the subselect is doing nothing in your query. You only need a subselect to do a multi-select filter. You are filtering to all categories which does nothing.

So you could simplify the query like this with the same results:

```
SELECT   ([Measures].[Internet Average Sales Amount]) ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```